# Mutex algorithm for a simple key-value storage

Tags: algorithm, locking, mutex, key-value-store

Is there an algorithm to allow reliable mutex using a key-value storage that only supports `set()` and `get()` operations plus current time check?

Some service API offers in-memory [storage](https://vk.com/dev/storage) with only simple `set(key, value)` and `get(key)` methods. I learned that Redis has a very nice distributed locks [algorithm](https://redis.io/topics/distlock), that relies on the `NX` "non-existing" flag on insertion. This service does not have that feature - it will always set.

There is also a utility [method](https://vk.com/dev/utils.getServerTime) to get current server's time with seconds precision. It is possible to create simple stored procedures that run on server, so network delays can be ignored.

I was thinking of some delayed implementation:

1. get key to see if it exists (or exists and contains "free" value);
2. set key to current timestamp + client ID;
3. wait 1-2 seconds;
4. get the key to verify it still has this client's ID and a timestamp that is 1-2 seconds old;
5. only then consider the lock acquired. If #1 or #4 fails, consider locked by other client.

Is there a well-known algorithm like that?